# NetStandard / Net Framework reference hell

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-4.7

I have a NetStandard 1.6 library that references an external library (System.Runtime.Loader, fetched from NuGet). If I reference my NetStandard library from a Net Framework 4.7 Windows-application I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when running the Net Framework application.

Full exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Now, I know full what the exception message means but I haven't got the foggiest on how to solve it in this situation.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you referencing the project or the output library?

Comment: Could you try the latest VS 2017 Preview? It has special tooling that should fix this automatically

Comment: I don't know the correct this way or not, but we solved the same problem by doing the following: you need to add the same nuget package to the Windows application.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Seems I can't find solutions anywhere....

Comment: This issue is described in this article, which includes workarounds. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to right click on the visual studio solution, go to manage nuget packages for the solution and check the versions of the various libraries you have. Any conflicts between the libraries will be present in the 'consolidate' tab. Alternatively, try removing the library reference from the project's reference folder and adding it back.